# How do I use async and await in this code?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, async-await, frontend

I'm still learning flutter and I ran into a problem where I need a ListView element be created only after the user inputs the name of it but currently it gets created before that. I assume you use await and async here but I can't figure out how. Thanks.

I tried doing some things with Future functions and using await/async but nothing worked.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: const MyTile(),
    );
  }
}

class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDialog({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyDialog> createState() => _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }

  String myString = '';

  Future<void> _dialogBuilder(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Basic dialog title'),
          content: TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Enter',
            ),
            onSubmitted: (String value) {
              myString = value;
            }
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Add'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTile({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyTile> createState() => _MyTileState();
}

class _MyTileState extends State<MyTile> {
  int _tileCount = 0;

  void _addTiles()
  {
    setState(() {
      _tileCount += 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _tileCount,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index)
        {
          return ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
            trailing: Text(
              _MyDialogState().myString
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _addTiles();
          _MyDialogState()._dialogBuilder(context);
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: const MyTile(),
    );
  }
}

class MyTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTile({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyTile> createState() => _MyTileState();
}

class _MyTileState extends State<MyTile> {
  List<String> tiles = [];

  Future<void> addTile() async {
    final value = await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        final controller = TextEditingController();
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Basic dialog title'),
          content: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Enter',
            ),
            onSubmitted: (String value) {
              Navigator.pop(context, value);
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Add'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, controller.text);
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    if (value != null) {
      setState(() {
        tiles.add(value);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: tiles.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = tiles[index];
          return ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
            trailing: Text(item),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          addTile();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

##### Explanation:

1. *Removed MyDialog*: Removed the MyDialog class because we can do all the work we need directly in the _MyTileState class. It's simpler and easier to understand this way.
2. *Created a tiles list*: Instead of just keeping a number of how many tiles we have (_tileCount), we created a list of tiles. Each item in this list is a string, which is the name of the tile that the user enters.
3. *Changed _addTiles to addTile*: We changed this function quite a bit:

- Made it async so that it can pause and wait for the user to enter their text.
- The showDialog part is what pops up the alert dialog to ask the user for input. We set it up so that it will give us back a string, which is the text that the user enters.
- When the user types their text and hits 'Add', instead of changing myString right away, we tell the dialog to close and give us back the text that the user entered.
- The await keyword is like a pause button. It says, "Wait here until the dialog is closed and we have our string, then we can keep going."
- Once we have our text (and it's not empty), we add it to our tiles list. The setState part is Flutter's way of saying, "Hey, something changed! You need to redraw the screen to show the new tiles."

4. *Updated the build method*: In the list of tiles, instead of just making a fixed number of tiles, we make as many tiles as we have in our tiles list. And for each tile, we show the text that the user entered. The '+' button now calls our new addTile function.

Comment: doesn't really work, it gives the dialog prompt but never creates the ListView element

Comment: I've made an update please check. I introduced a TextEditingController.

Comment: also if you don't mind could you also explain the things you changed and why, would help out a lot in terms of understanding more about this part of flutter. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, I'll add an explanation.

Comment: I've added an explanation. @MantiS